# ajax $.get usage with php

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to implement a PHP script with AJAX. My code looks as below. Basically I have an array, `arrNodes`, that includes list of units. Each node in the array has gauges which I try to refresh with values from the PHP script. I run netsnmp for retriving cpu/memory usage.

When I run the program after a short time I get an XHR timeout for one of the PHP scripts that should run, while the units I audit are available.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here but it seems that it's related to the timing of the `$.get`, any ideas?

```
var arrNodes = new Array;
window.onload = function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        function ajaxCpu(i, ip, os, com) {
            $.get("ajax/cpu.php", {
                Uip: ip,
                Uos: os,
                Ucom: snmpcomm
            }, function (value) {
                window["g1_" + i].refresh(value)
            });
        }

        function ajaxMem(i, ip, os, com) {
            $.get("ajax/mem.php", {
                Uip: ip,
                Uos: os,
                Ucom: snmpcomm
            }, function (value) {
                window["g2_" + i].refresh(value)
            });
        }

        function ajaxTmp(i, ip, os, com) {
            $.get("ajax/tmp3.php", {
                Uip: ip,
                Uos: os,
                Ucom: snmpcomm
            }, function (value) {
                window["g3_" + i].refresh(value)
            });
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < arrNodes.length; i++) {
            var path0 = document.getElementById("g1_" + i);
            var ip = path0.getAttribute('data-ip');

            var path1 = document.getElementById("g1_" + i);
            var snmpcomm = path1.getAttribute('data-snmpcomunity');

            var path2 = document.getElementById("g1_" + i);
            var os = path2.getAttribute('data-os');

            ajaxCpu(i, ip, os, snmpcomm);
            ajaxMem(i, ip, os, snmpcomm);
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

Here's the PHP:

```
$Uip = $_GET['Uip'];
$Uos = $_GET['Uos'];
$Ucom = $_GET['Ucom'];
snmp_set_valueretrieval(SNMP_VALUE_PLAIN);
$cpu = snmpget($Uip,$Ucom,".1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.10.1.3.1",  1000);                     

$t = (float)($cpu);
echo $t ;
```

Comment: If your problem is a timeout from the request it means that the server is not responding quick enough and your problem lies there. Please add your PHP code to the question.

Comment: here is my cpu php script  :                                     $Uip = $_GET['Uip'];
$Uos = $_GET['Uos'];
$Ucom = $_GET['Ucom'];                                                                                                                          
snmp_set_valueretrieval(SNMP_VALUE_PLAIN);
$cpu = snmpget($Uip,$Ucom,".1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.10.1.3.1", 1000);                     

$t = (float)($cpu);
echo $t ;                                                                            sorry about how its looks like ....

Comment: Please Post your code in question instread of comment.